# Invalidating OpenID session on Google Identity

Tags: google-identity

Users can log into my site using Google Identity, via the Open ID protocol. However I'm not sure how to invalidate their session with google identity when they click log out. At the moment, I can invalidate their session cookies on my site, but if the user selects to log in with Google Identity again, it won't prompt them for credentials again, because they already logged in. Options I've tried to resolve this:

- The `end_session_endpoint` from the [Session Management spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html), but Google Identity doesn't implement that.
- The `frontchannel_logout_uri` from the [FrontChannel Logout spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html), but Google Identity doesn't implement that either.
- The `backchannel_logout_uri` from the [BackChannel Logout spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html), but Google Identity doesn't implement that either.
- Hitting https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout in an iframe when the user logs out, but this terminates their Google login everywhere, not just my site.

Is there a supported way of invalidating Open ID sessions for Google Identity?